# How to import a list of file in Python using raw_input

Tags: python, input, directory, raw-input, os.path

I wish to import a list of files ex:

```
'E:\\mytest\\test_00.txt'
'E:\\mytest\\test_01.txt'
'E:\\mytest\\test_02.txt'


INPUT_txt = raw_input("Input File(s): ")
element = map(str, INPUT_txt.split(","))
for filename in element:
    print os.path.abspath(filename)
    print os.path.isfile(filename)
```

I got this result

```
E:\\mytest\\test_00.txt
True    
C:\PythonScript\ E:\\mytest\\test_01.txt
False    
C:\PythonScript\ E:\\mytest\\test_02.txt
False
```

only first file (test_00.txt) is True because located in the right directory

Comment: What does `print INPUT_txt` returns?

Comment: Did you have a problem? A question? You've shown us some code and some output, but it's still not clear what you're asking.

Comment: If you had spaces in your input, those are likely your problem. You're splitting on commas, so the filenames keep the whitespace.

Comment: There is a way to resolve this problem? import with and without the whitespace? Thanks in advance

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary sorry where is print INPUT_txt?

Comment: @Gianni I wanted to know what does `INPUT_txt` contains.

Comment: INPUT_txt = E:\\mytest\\test_00.txt, E:\\mytest\\test_01.txt, E:\\mytest\\test_02.txt using raw_input comand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `map(str, INPUT_txt.split(","))` - the elements are already strings. Other than that, its just a matter of cleaning up the split filenames by stripping whitespace.

```
INPUT_txt = raw_input("Input File(s): ")
element = [ss for ss in (s.strip() for s in INPUT_txt.split(",")) if ss]
for filename in element:
    print os.path.abspath(filename)
    print os.path.isfile(filename)
```

Comment: I accidentally typed 'strip' instead of 'split' when tidying up the post. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os

INPUT_txt = raw_input("Input File(s): ")
element = map(str, INPUT_txt.split(","))
for filename in element:
    print filename
    print os.path.isfile(filename)
```

pay attention to the separator that you are using (in your case ","), for example a sequence of input:

```
Input file(s): ..\\file1.txt,C:\\file2.txt,results\\file3.txt
```

will generate a correct output, whereas:

```
Input file(s): ..\\file1.txt, C:\\file2.txt , results\\file3.txt
```

will not.